# Cannot Export Excel in Laravel with 404 Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am having some trouble exporting my Excel file in Laravel. When I click the export button, the page displays "404 Not Found". I tried `php artisan route:clear` or `php artisan route:cache` but it does not work.  [image]

Hopefully, you can help me solve the problem. Here are my codes:

**App\Teacher.php:**

```php
    <?php
    namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Teacher extends Model {
        protected $guarded = [];
        protected $table = 'teachers';
    }
```

**App\Exports\TeacherExport.php:**

```php
    <?php
    namespace App\Exports;

    use App\Teacher;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

    class TeacherExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings {    
        public function headings():array {
            return [
                'id',
                'name',
                'email',
                'created_at',
                'updated_at'
            ];
        }
        /**
         * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
         */
        public function collection() {
            return Teacher::all();
        }
    }
```

**App\Controllers\TeachersController.php:**

```php
    public function exportTeacherIntoExcel() {
        return Excel::download(new TeacherExport, 'teacher.xlsx');
    }
```

**web.php:**

```php
Route::get('/teacher/export-excel', 'TeachersController@exportTeacherIntoExcel');
```

**resources\views\teacher\index.blade.php:**

```html
    @extends('home')
    @section('content')
        <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">
                    Danh sách giáo viên
                </h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                    Bạn có thể tìm tất cả thông tin giáo viên ở đây:
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="/teacher/create" class="btn btn-info">
            Thêm giáo viên
        </a>
        <a href="/teacher/export-excel" class="btn btn-success">
            Xuất file
        </a>
        <table class="table thead-light">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">
                        ID
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        Tên giáo viên
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        Địa chỉ Mail
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        Tính năng
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        Tính năng
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($teacher as $teacher)
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">
                            {{$teacher->id}}
                        </th>
                        <td>
                            {{$teacher->name}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{$teacher->email}}
                        </td>
                        <!-- <td>Tính năng</td> -->
                        <td>  
                            <a href="/teacher/{{$teacher->id}}/edit" class = "btn btn-success">
                                Sửa
                            </a>     
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="/teacher/{{$teacher->id}}" class="btn btn-danger">
                                Xóa
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach 
            </tbody>
        </table>
    @endsection
```

Comment: have you try `dd()` inside controller ? req. rech there or not

Comment: Yes, I tried. But, the message "404 Not Found" still exists

Comment: And when I check my route, it still shows `GET|HEAD | teacher/export-excel              |                  | App\Http\Controllers\TeachersController@exportTeacherIntoExcel`

Comment: then run `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: you seem to have xampp running as well, make sure to have only one web server occupying that port.

Comment: as @KamleshPaul say, di you dd BEFORE the export performs? If you create another route + method in controller, it works?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, everyone. I have already solved my problem. The issue here is the order of the route. In my route, I fixed it like this and it works.
`web.php:`

```
/**
 * Teacher
 */
Route::get('/teacher/export-excel', 'TeachersController@exportTeacherIntoExcel');
Route::get('/teacher', 'TeachersController@index');
Route::get('/teacher/create', 'TeachersController@create');
Route::post('/teacher', 'TeachersController@store');
Route::get('/teacher/{teacher}/edit','TeachersController@edit');
Route::patch('/teacher/{teacher}', 'TeachersController@update');
Route::get('/teacher/{teacher}', 'TeachersController@destroy');
```